# SharedPreference android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sharedpreferences

why is this? Auto Bid returns to off if open already opened another activity?

I previously declared the SettingPreference in the onClick method, then I dragged it out to move to onCreate

**SettingPreference.java**

```
public class SettingPreference {
private static String KEY_AUTO_BID = "AUTO_BID";

 private SharedPreferences pref;

    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    public SettingPreference(Context context) {
        pref = context.getSharedPreferences(MyConfig.SETTING_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }
...
public void updateAutoBid(String autoBid) {
        editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putString(KEY_AUTO_BID, autoBid);
        editor.apply();
    }
...
}
```

**DashboardFragment.java**

```
public class DashboardFragment extends Fragment  implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {
private SettingPreference sp;

...

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();

        sp = new SettingPreference(activity);
btnauto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //SettingPreference sp = new SettingPreference(activity);
                if(sp.getSetting()[0].equals("OFF")){
                    sp.updateAutoBid("ON");
                    btnauto.setText(R.string.on);
                    //Log.i("AUTO_BID" , sp.getSetting()[0]);
                    Toast.makeText  (activity, "Autobid Aktif.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    sp.updateAutoBid("OFF");
                    btnauto.setText(R.string.off);
                    //Log.i("AUTO_BID", sp.getSetting()[0]);
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "Autobid Nonaktif.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        if(sp.getSetting()[0].equals("OFF")){
            //sp.updateAutoBid("ON");
            btnauto.setText(R.string.on);
            Log.i("AUTO_BID" , sp.getSetting()[0]);
            //Toast.makeText(activity, "Autobid Aktif.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else if(sp.getSetting()[0].equals("ON")){
            //sp.updateAutoBid("OFF");
            btnauto.setText(R.string.off);
            Log.i("AUTO_BID", sp.getSetting()[0]);
            //Toast.makeText(activity, "Autobid Nonaktif.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else {
            //Toast.makeText(activity,"Auto Bid Not Update", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
}
```

can you help me guys ?

Comment: You can look how you can use. My [project](https://github.com/kasimoz/Weather_Android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/kasim/weatherAndroid/Helpers/SharedPreferenceManager.java)

Comment: I have found the problem, the problem lies in the  if else upside